# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dom' of null

Tags: extjs

When click first time on showbutton then window open perfectly but when i close window and  again open this then its giving error("Cannot read property 'dom' of null ") on line 'shiftWindow.show();'. Any help is appreciated.

```
var shiftWindow = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    title: 'Edit Shift',
    resizable: false,
    id: 'shiftwindow',
    width: 465,
    //bodyPadding: 5,
    modal: true,
    store: shiftStorePlanner,

    items: {
        xtype: 'form',
        id: 'idFormShift',
        bodyPadding: 10,
        items: shiftViewModelPlannerData
    },
    buttons: [{
        text: 'Save',
        cls: 'planner-save-button',
        overCls: 'planner-save-button-over',
        handler: function () {
            var wi = this.up('.window');
            var form = Ext.getCmp('idFormShift');
            if (form.isValid()) {
                shiftTimemappingarray = [];
                //  getShiftTime();
                setShiftTimeDetails();
            }
        }
    }, {
        text: 'Cancel',
        handler: function () {
            this.up('.window').close();
        }
    }]
});
shiftWindow.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling `close()` on the window, the window is destroyed. It no longer exists in the DOM. You'll have to create it again before calling `show()`.

Alternatively, instead of closing it, you can `hide()` the window. Then it will remain and not require another creation. Note that the upper right-hand 'x' will still fire the close event.

Answer (score 1):

On Cancel click of your window,

instead of using

```
this.up('.window').close();
```

You should use

```
this.up('.window').destroy();
```

because then only it will destroy the whole window including dom. So everytime you open it, it will new and fresh.. ;)

Comment: Can you please comment whether you find the answer useful or not?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just not define a div element in the body like me.

```
<div id="helloWorldPanel">
</div>
```